# RTP payload Depacketization for bandwidth Efficient mode for AMR

Tags: rtp, amr

Do anybody have idea that how can i convert the RTP packetized AMR audio content into standalone AMR file?

I have the dump of RTP payload and I want to convert it into the standalone AMR file. I have followed up RFC 3267 and RFC 4867 and understood the byte pattern but I havenot found anywhere the also where i can see how can i packetize the AMR frames into RTP or vice-versa.

Regards
Nitin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done and depacketize the content using the answer givne on the link

[AMR Raw Output from Wireshark not playing in players](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225661/amr-raw-output-from-wireshark-not-playing-in-players)