# PCAP to AMR Conversion with DTX

Tags: wireshark, pcap, libpcap, amr

I am trying to convert a PCAP containing a RTP Payload with an octet-aligned AMR-WB payload to a playable AMR file.

Regarding the AMR storage format described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4867#section-4 between SID frames NO_DATA (0x7C) frames need to be inserted.
This is especially important when using DTX (discontinuous transmission) mode.

The question in [AMR Raw Output from Wireshark not playing in players](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225661/amr-raw-output-from-wireshark-not-playing-in-players/18086585#18086585) describes a way to convert a single PCAP UDP packet to AMR but does not consider a whole packet flow where packets need to be concatenated or NO_DATA frames need to be inserted after SID frames in DTX mode.

I managed converting it parsing every packet with PCAP.net and now wonder whether my output is correct. I could not find any information on which audio player supports AMR-WB in DTX Mode, though.

VLC Player plays it correctly with the speech pauses, but shows the wrong total time of the file and when converting it to *.wav (using VLC), there will be no speech pauses anymore.

I would like to analyze my speech data using a tool as audacity which shows the spectrum of the sound. Unfortunately, audacity shows loud bangs in the speech pauses (see picture). Therefore, I do not know whether audacity just does not support DTX or my output is corrupt?

It would be great if you can help.

[image: Audacity Bangs in Speech Pauses (SID+NO_DATA Frames)]

Here the output Soundfile (just use a hex editor and call it *.amr):

```
00000000h: 23 21 41 4D 52 2D 57 42 0A 4C EB FF BD F3 C7 7C ; #!AMR-WB.Lëÿ½óÇ|
00000010h: 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB ; |Lëÿ½ó×|||||||Lë
00000020h: FF BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD E3 ; ÿ½³—|||||||Lëÿ½ã
00000030h: D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 97 7C 7C ; ×|||||||Lëÿ½³—||
00000040h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lëÿ½³—|||||
00000050h: 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lëÿ½³×|||||||L
00000060h: EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD ; ëÿ½³×|||||||Lëÿ½
00000070h: F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 97 7C ; ó×|||||||Lëÿ½³—|
00000080h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lëÿ½³—||||
00000090h: 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lëÿ½ó×|||||||
000000a0h: 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF ; Lëÿ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ
000000b0h: BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 ; ½³—|||||||Lëÿ½ó×
000000c0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lëÿ½ó×|||
000000d0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lëÿ½³×||||||
000000e0h: 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB ; |Lëÿ½ó—|||||||Lë
000000f0h: FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 ; ÿ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ½ó
00000100h: D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C ; ×|||||||Lëÿ½ó×||
00000110h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lëÿ½³—|||||
00000120h: 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lëÿ½³×|||||||L
00000130h: EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD ; ëÿ½³×|||||||Lëÿ½
00000140h: F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C ; ó×|||||||Lëÿ½ó—|
00000150h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lëÿ½ó×||||
00000160h: 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lëÿ½³×|||||||
00000170h: 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF ; Lëÿ½³×|||||||Lëÿ
00000180h: BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 ; ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ½ó—
00000190h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lëÿ½ó×|||
000001a0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 F7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lëÿ½ó÷||||||
000001b0h: 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB ; |Lëÿ½³×|||||||Lë
000001c0h: FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD 63 ; ÿ½ó—|||||||Lëÿ½c
000001d0h: D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C ; ×|||||||Lëÿ½³×||
000001e0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lëÿ½³×|||||
000001f0h: 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lëÿ½ó—|||||||L
00000200h: EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD ; ëÿ½³×|||||||Lëÿ½
00000210h: B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C ; ³×|||||||Lëÿ½³×|
00000220h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lëÿ½ó×||||
00000230h: 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lëÿ½³×|||||||
00000240h: 4C EB FF BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF ; Lëÿ½³—|||||||Lëÿ
00000250h: BD F3 B7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 ; ½ó·|||||||Lëÿ½ó—
00000260h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lëÿ½ó×|||
00000270h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lëÿ½ó×||||||
00000280h: 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB ; |Lëÿ½³—|||||||Lë
00000290h: FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 ; ÿ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ½ó
000002a0h: 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C ; —|||||||Lëÿ½³×||
000002b0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lëÿ½³×|||||
000002c0h: 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lëÿ½ó×|||||||L
000002d0h: EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD ; ëÿ½³×|||||||Lëÿ½
000002e0h: F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C ; ó×|||||||Lëÿ½ó×|
000002f0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lëÿ½³—||||
00000300h: 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lëÿ½ó×|||||||
00000310h: 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF ; Lëÿ½³×|||||||Lëÿ
00000320h: BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 ; ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ½ó×
00000330h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lëÿ½³×|||
00000340h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lëÿ½ó×||||||
00000350h: 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB ; |Lëÿ½³×|||||||Lë
00000360h: FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 ; ÿ½ó—|||||||Lëÿ½³
00000370h: D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C ; ×|||||||Lëÿ½³×||
00000380h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lëÿ½ó×|||||
00000390h: 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD A3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lëÿ½£—|||||||L
000003a0h: EB FF BD E3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD ; ëÿ½ã×|||||||Lëÿ½
000003b0h: F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C ; ó×|||||||Lëÿ½ó—|
000003c0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lëÿ½ó—||||
000003d0h: 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lëÿ½ó×|||||||
000003e0h: 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF ; Lëÿ½³×|||||||Lëÿ
000003f0h: BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 ; ½³×|||||||Lëÿ½³×
00000400h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lëÿ½ó—|||
00000410h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lëÿ½ó×||||||
00000420h: 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB ; |Lëÿ½³×|||||||Lë
00000430h: FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 ; ÿ½ó—|||||||Lëÿ½³
00000440h: 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 97 7C 7C ; —|||||||Lëÿ½³—||
00000450h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lëÿ½³×|||||
00000460h: 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lëÿ½ó—|||||||L
00000470h: EB FF BD E3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD ; ëÿ½ã—|||||||Lëÿ½
00000480h: B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C ; ³×|||||||Lëÿ½ó—|
00000490h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lëÿ½³×||||
000004a0h: 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lëÿ½ó—|||||||
000004b0h: 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF ; Lëÿ½³×|||||||Lëÿ
000004c0h: BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 ; ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ½³×
000004d0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lëÿ½ó—|||
000004e0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lëÿ½³×||||||
000004f0h: 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB ; |Lëÿ½³×|||||||Lë
00000500h: FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 ; ÿ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ½³
00000510h: D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C ; ×|||||||Lëÿ½ó×||
00000520h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lëÿ½ó—|||||
00000530h: 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lëÿ½³—|||||||L
00000540h: EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD ; ëÿ½³×|||||||Lëÿ½
00000550h: F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C ; ó×|||||||Lëÿ½ó×|
00000560h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lëÿ½³×||||
00000570h: 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lëÿ½³—|||||||
00000580h: 4C EB FF BD E3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF ; Lëÿ½ã×|||||||Lëÿ
00000590h: BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD E3 D7 ; ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ½ã×
000005a0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lëÿ½³×|||
000005b0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lëÿ½ó×||||||
000005c0h: 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB ; |Lëÿ½ó×|||||||Lë
000005d0h: FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 ; ÿ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ½³
000005e0h: D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C ; ×|||||||Lëÿ½ó×||
000005f0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lëÿ½ó×|||||
00000600h: 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lëÿ½³×|||||||L
00000610h: EB FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD ; ëÿ½ó—|||||||Lëÿ½
00000620h: F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C ; ó×|||||||Lëÿ½ó×|
00000630h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lëÿ½ó×||||
00000640h: 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lëÿ½ó×|||||||
00000650h: 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF ; Lëÿ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ
00000660h: BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 ; ½³×|||||||Lëÿ½³×
00000670h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lëÿ½³—|||
00000680h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lëÿ½ó—||||||
00000690h: 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB ; |Lëÿ½ó—|||||||Lë
000006a0h: FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD E3 ; ÿ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ½ã
000006b0h: 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C ; —|||||||Lëÿ½³×||
000006c0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lëÿ½³×|||||
000006d0h: 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lëÿ½³×|||||||L
000006e0h: EB FF BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD ; ëÿ½³—|||||||Lëÿ½
000006f0h: B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C ; ³×|||||||Lëÿ½ó×|
00000700h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lëÿ½³×||||
00000710h: 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD A3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lëÿ½£×|||||||
00000720h: 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF ; Lëÿ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ
00000730h: BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 ; ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ½ó×
00000740h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lëÿ½ó×|||
00000750h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lëÿ½ó×||||||
00000760h: 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB ; |Lëÿ½ó×|||||||Lë
00000770h: FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 ; ÿ½³×|||||||Lëÿ½³
00000780h: 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C ; —|||||||Lëÿ½³×||
00000790h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lëÿ½ó×|||||
000007a0h: 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD E3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lëÿ½ã×|||||||L
000007b0h: EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD ; ëÿ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ½
000007c0h: E3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C ; ã×|||||||Lëÿ½³×|
000007d0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lëÿ½³—||||
000007e0h: 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lëÿ½³×|||||||
000007f0h: 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF ; Lëÿ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ
00000800h: BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 ; ½³—|||||||Lëÿ½³×
00000810h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD E3 D7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lëÿ½ã×|||
00000820h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lëÿ½ó—||||||
00000830h: 7C 4C EB FF BD E3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB ; |Lëÿ½ã—|||||||Lë
00000840h: FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 ; ÿ½³×|||||||Lëÿ½ó
00000850h: D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C ; ×|||||||Lëÿ½ó×||
00000860h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lëÿ½³×|||||
00000870h: 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lëÿ½ó—|||||||L
00000880h: EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD ; ëÿ½ó×|||||||Lëÿ½
00000890h: F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C ; ó×|||||||Lëÿ½ó—|
000008a0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lëÿ½ó×||||
000008b0h: 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lëÿ½³×|||||||
000008c0h: 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF ; Lëÿ½³×|||||||Lëÿ
000008d0h: BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 ; ½³—|||||||Lëÿ½³×
000008e0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lëÿ½ó×|||
000008f0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lëÿ½ó×||||||
00000900h: 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB ; |Lëÿ½³×|||||||Lë
00000910h: FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 ; ÿ½ó—|||||||Lëÿ½ó
00000920h: D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C ; ×|||||||Lëÿ½ó×||
00000930h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lëÿ½³×|||||
00000940h: 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD 63 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lëÿ½c—|||||||L
00000950h: EB FF BD B3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD ; ëÿ½³—|||||||Lëÿ½
00000960h: F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 D7 7C ; ó—|||||||Lëÿ½ó×|
00000970h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lëÿ½³×||||
00000980h: 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF BD F3 97 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lëÿ½ó—|||||||
00000990h: 4C EB FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C EB FF ; Lëÿ½³×|||||||Lëÿ
000009a0h: BD F3 F7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 ; ½ó÷|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×
000009b0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 F7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lÿÿ½ó÷|||
000009c0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lÿÿ½ó×||||||
000009d0h: 7C 4C FF FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF ; |Lÿÿ½³×|||||||Lÿ
000009e0h: FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 ; ÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó
000009f0h: F7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C ; ÷|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×||
00000a00h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||
00000a10h: 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lÿÿ½³×|||||||L
00000a20h: FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD ; ÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½
00000a30h: F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD E3 D7 7C ; ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ã×|
00000a40h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lÿÿ½³×||||
00000a50h: 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||
00000a60h: 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF ; Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ
00000a70h: BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 ; ½³×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×
00000a80h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lÿÿ½ó×|||
00000a90h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lÿÿ½ó×||||||
00000aa0h: 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF ; |Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿ
00000ab0h: FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 ; ÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó
00000ac0h: D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C ; ×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×||
00000ad0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||
00000ae0h: 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||L
00000af0h: FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD ; ÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½
00000b00h: F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C ; ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×|
00000b10h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lÿÿ½ó×||||
00000b20h: 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||
00000b30h: 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF ; Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ
00000b40h: BD E3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 ; ½ã×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×
00000b50h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lÿÿ½ó×|||
00000b60h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lÿÿ½ó×||||||
00000b70h: 7C 4C FF FF BD E3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF ; |Lÿÿ½ã×|||||||Lÿ
00000b80h: FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 ; ÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó
00000b90h: D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C ; ×|||||||Lÿÿ½³×||
00000ba0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||
00000bb0h: 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||L
00000bc0h: FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD ; ÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½
00000bd0h: F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD B3 D7 7C ; ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½³×|
00000be0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD E3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lÿÿ½ã×||||
00000bf0h: 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||
00000c00h: 4C FF FF BD E3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF ; Lÿÿ½ã×|||||||Lÿÿ
00000c10h: BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 ; ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×
00000c20h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lÿÿ½ó×|||
00000c30h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lÿÿ½ó×||||||
00000c40h: 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF ; |Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿ
00000c50h: FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 ; ÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó
00000c60h: D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C ; ×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×||
00000c70h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||
00000c80h: 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||L
00000c90h: FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD ; ÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½
00000ca0h: F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C ; ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×|
00000cb0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lÿÿ½ó×||||
00000cc0h: 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lÿÿ½³×|||||||
00000cd0h: 4C FF FF BD E3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF ; Lÿÿ½ã×|||||||Lÿÿ
00000ce0h: BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 ; ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×
00000cf0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lÿÿ½ó×|||
00000d00h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lÿÿ½ó×||||||
00000d10h: 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF ; |Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿ
00000d20h: FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 ; ÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó
00000d30h: D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C ; ×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×||
00000d40h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||
00000d50h: 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||L
00000d60h: FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD ; ÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½
00000d70h: F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C ; ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×|
00000d80h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lÿÿ½³×||||
00000d90h: 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||
00000da0h: 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF ; Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ
00000db0h: BD E3 F7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 ; ½ã÷|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×
00000dc0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lÿÿ½ó×|||
00000dd0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lÿÿ½ó×||||||
00000de0h: 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF ; |Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿ
00000df0h: FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 ; ÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó
00000e00h: D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C ; ×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×||
00000e10h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||
00000e20h: 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||L
00000e30h: FF FF BD D3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD ; ÿÿ½Ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½
00000e40h: F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C ; ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×|
00000e50h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lÿÿ½ó×||||
00000e60h: 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||
00000e70h: 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF ; Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ
00000e80h: BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 ; ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×
00000e90h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lÿÿ½ó×|||
00000ea0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lÿÿ½ó×||||||
00000eb0h: 7C 4C FF FF BD B3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF ; |Lÿÿ½³×|||||||Lÿ
00000ec0h: FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 ; ÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó
00000ed0h: D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C ; ×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×||
00000ee0h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||
00000ef0h: 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C ; ||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||L
00000f00h: FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD ; ÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½
00000f10h: F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C ; ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×|
00000f20h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||||Lÿÿ½ó×||||
00000f30h: 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; |||Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||
00000f40h: 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF ; Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ
00000f50h: BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 ; ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó×
00000f60h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C ; |||||||Lÿÿ½ó×|||
00000f70h: 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C ; ||||Lÿÿ½ó×||||||
00000f80h: 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF ; |Lÿÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿ
00000f90h: FF BD F3 D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD F3 ; ÿ½ó×|||||||Lÿÿ½ó
00000fa0h: D7 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 7C 4C FF FF BD E3 D7 7C 7C ; ×|||||||Lÿÿ½ã×||
00000fb0h: 7C 7C 7C                                        ; |||
```

So,

1. Is it an Audacity problem because it does not interpret DTX frames? What player would be able to play it else correctly?
2. Is my AMR file wrong?

Regards

Comment: I am attempting to do something similar myself, but when I save the payloads from wireshark I get something I don't understand. I can see the normal frames and the SID frames but after a group of SID frames there is a lot of zero data. It seems to be dependent on the number of SID frames so I assume it is related and wireshark generates this data on its own. What I don't understand is how these correlate to the AMR storage format. I don't see anything similar in your hexdump, but have you seen something like this?

Comment: @Chris I saw the same thing (a lot of zeroes) from wireshark raw file. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Grassright It's been a while since I was working on this. I think I figured that the zeroes were there to fill in the empty space of the SID frames. I think I ended up just moving away from pcaps with SID frames at the time. Sorry I can't help much, this was quite a while ago when I was working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my file was correct.

Problem is Audacity and all the other players.

The solution is to use the reference codec found here to decode the created amr file:

http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/26-series.htm

for AMR-WB it would be e.g. TS26.173